# generating textbox inside a table using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Suppose this is the prepare table below. and each of 3 row there was a textbox and beside them there where 2 buttons the + or add and - for delete. when i click + in a row, a new textbox will be generated and when i click - the textbox will delete. like the sample below:
[image: My question or sample that i cant do by my self ;-(]

---

Could anyone suggest the snippet for this step or procedure?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

you could write something on these lines:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){

var counter = 2;

$("#addButton").click(function () {

if(counter>10){
        alert("Only 10 textboxes are allowed");
        return false;
}   

var newTextBoxDiv = $(document.createElement('div'))
     .attr("id", 'TextBoxDiv' + counter);

newTextBoxDiv.after().html('<label>Textbox #'+ counter + ' : </label>' +
      '<input type="text" name="textbox' + counter + 
      '" id="textbox' + counter + '" value="" >');

newTextBoxDiv.appendTo("#TextBoxesGroup");


counter++;
 });

 $("#removeButton").click(function () {
if(counter==1){
      alert("No more textbox to remove");
      return false;
   }   

counter--;

    $("#TextBoxDiv" + counter).remove();

 });
});
</script>
```

If you do not want to create the div on the fly, you can find the id of your last table row, add 1 to it, create the table row, and then append the textbox creation html to it.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the html structure is as follows

```
<table border = "1">
<thead>
    <tr><td> Text Boxes </td></tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr><td><button class="add-text-box">+</button><button class="remove-text-box">-</button></td></tr>
    <tr><td><button class="add-text-box">+</button><button class="remove-text-box">-</button></td></tr>
    <tr><td><button class="add-text-box">+</button><button class="remove-text-box">-</button></td></tr>
</tbody>
```

​
the following jquery snippet should work

```
$(".add-text-box").click(function(){
    $(this).parent().prepend(" <input class='text-box' /> <br>");
});

$(".remove-text-box").click(function(){
    textboxes = $(this).parent().find('.text-box'); 
    $(textboxes).last().remove();
    if (textboxes.length === 0) {
        $(this).siblings().remove();
        $(this).remove();
    }        
});
```

​
You can see it in action [here](http://jsfiddle.net/4arTn/3/)

Comment: kidmenot nice work but the problem is when i click - sign and only 1 textbox is remain it should be gone together with the buttons or the row instead thx